# set divider between two columns in janous grid

Tags: gridview, grid, janus, winapp

I have a janous grid , and i need put divider between two columns or set thick line between columns.
how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Grid's Property `OwnerDrawnAreas` to `ColumnSetHeaders` then utilize the event DrawGridArea to draw the ColumnSet with your custom layout.

Comment: thanks for response . property OwnerDrawAreas not any value equal ColumnSetHeaders.
can you show any example or more explain about it?